# Yii2 Rest Controller and public variable

Tags: rest, activerecord, yii2

I have made a REST controller with Yii2 framework. When I try to retrieve a record from my database through an `ActiveRecord` model, `JsonFormatter` give me only real attributes. How can configure `JsonFormatter` to give me also public variable?
This is my code:

Controller

```
class MyController extends yii\rest\ActiveController
{
    ...

    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $struct = \common\models\Struct::find()->where(['id' => '285'])->One();
        if ($struct) {
            return $struct;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Model

```
/**
* property string $id;
* property string $name;
*/
class Struct extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $test;
    ...
    public function afterFind()
    {
        parent::afterFind();
        $this->test = 'ok';
    }
}
```

result of request

```
{"id":1,"name": "ciccio"}
```

but if I print variable with `print_r()`, I have all object

```
\app\models\Struct object
(
    [test] => ok
    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => ciccio
    )
)
```

How can I get the variable `test` property without add an empty field on my database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [`ActiveRecord::fields()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#fields()-detail) method to add the custom field that is declared as the public property of the class. The `fields()` method returns the names of the columns whose values have been populated into this record.

Looking at your code you are trying to set the `test` property inside the `afterFind()` and want that value to be reflected against all rows when you call the `Model::find()` method. If that is correct then add the following inside your model:

```
public function fields() {
    $fields = parent::fields();
    $fields['test'] = 'test';
    return $fields;
}
```

Now when you call the  `\common\models\Struct::find()` it will return

```
{"id":1,"name": "ciccio","test":"ok"}
```

Comment: Work like a charm. Thank You!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

keep all you showed and then Override **getAttributes**

```
public function getAttributes($names = null, $except = [])
    {
        return array_merge(['test'=>$this->test], parent::getAttributes($names, $except));
    }
```

and in your controller isted of return like this: `return $struct;`
do it like this: `return $struct->attributes;`